# How can I show that $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is uncountable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I saw somewhere the the cantor set is in bijection with $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, so this mean that $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is uncountable. But how can I show that $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is uncountable ?

Comment: Duplicate: search site for http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=power+set+uncountable

Comment: HINT: Given $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, think about the set $X=\{n: n\not\in f(n)\}$. Can $X=f(i)$ for any $i$? What does this say about the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: @MathBeginner: What is the definition of the *cantor set*?